# auto convert UTC date to local time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone, utc

We are developing an ASP.net application which stores the date and time in UTC format. This application will be used globally. But each location will run separate instance  of application and will have its own database.

Is it possible to auto convert the date and time when user is viewing the date time value without having to get the local time zone (Like EST,CST,PST ...) in C#.?

I can use as

```
DateTime convertTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(
    DateTime.UtcNow, 
    TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

but was wondering if I can make some application wide settings (in web.config ) or somewhere ... which will display all `DateTime` in local time zone format ?

Comment: You will need to specify that you need to see a date in local time. A shorter way of converting it would be `date.ToLocalTime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ASP.Net application, `TimeZoneInfo.Local` refers to the time zone of the *server* - not the user.  In general, it's a bad practice to rely on the server's time zone to be set to anything in particular.

The behavior you're asking about is already covered by the `DateTime.Now` property, which uses the local time zone, much in the way you showed in your code.

No, there's no way to use web.config settings or any other settings to globally change the local time zone.  That's a per-machine setting, and is system-wide across all applications.

One approach you might consider is to pass UTC values down to the client, and use client-side JavaScript to convert to the user's local time.   But if you have server-side conversions to do, then you *must* know the time zone of the user explicitly.